# Elasticsearch [5.6] Sum Aggregations Losing Precision?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, sum

I'm trying to do a sum aggregation of amounts ($21.28 for example). But in the aggregation result, it only shows (21.0)

I've also tried changing the type of the mapping to float, and I got the same results.

The query itself looks like:

```
'aggs': {
    'total': {
        'sum': {
            'field': 'amount'
         }
     }
}
```

And the mapping looks like:

```
'amount': {
    'type': 'double',
    'index': 'not_analyzed',
    'store': False
},
```

And finally, here's the result, I've omitted some data but the important bits are the amounts:

```
{
    'took': 3,
    'aggregations': {'total': {'value': 21.0}},
    'hits': {'total': 1, 'max_score': 0.51623213, 
    'hits': [
        {
            '_score': 0.51623213,
            '_index': 'some_index',
            '_type': 'donation',
            '_source': {
                'amount': 21.28,
                'created_on': '2019-06-15T01:37:42.451249+00:00'
            }
        }
    ]},
    'timed_out': False,
    '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}
}
```

I'd expect to see 21.28 in the results, and not 21.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to update to Elasticsearch 6.x